How to completely hide the title bar in a .NET MAUI application on Windows while retaining resizability?
I am developing a .NET MAUI Blazor Hybrid App for Windows, and I want to hide the default title bar completely while keeping the window resizable. I've tried modifying the MauiProgram.cs file to achieve this.
I added the following code to MauiProgram.cs:
#if WINDOWS
builder.ConfigureLifecycleEvents((events) =>
{
    events.AddWindows(wndLifeCycleBuilder =>
    {
        wndLifeCycleBuilder.OnWindowCreated((w) =>
        {
            IntPtr nativeWindowHandle = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(w);
            WindowId win32WindowsId = Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(nativeWindowHandle);
            AppWindow winuiAppWindow = AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(win32WindowsId);
            if (winuiAppWindow.Presenter is OverlappedPresenter p)
            {
                p.IsResizable = true;
                p.SetBorderAndTitleBar(false, false);
            }
        });
    });
});
#endif

With this code, the title bar is hidden, but there is still a white space at the top.

When I updated the code to:
#if WINDOWS
builder.ConfigureLifecycleEvents((events) =>
{
    events.AddWindows(wndLifeCycleBuilder =>
    {
        wndLifeCycleBuilder.OnWindowCreated((w) =>
        {
            IntPtr nativeWindowHandle = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(w);
            WindowId win32WindowsId = Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(nativeWindowHandle);
            AppWindow winuiAppWindow = AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(win32WindowsId);
            if (winuiAppWindow.Presenter is OverlappedPresenter p)
            {
                p.IsResizable = false;
                p.SetBorderAndTitleBar(false, false);
            }
        });
    });
});
#endif

The white space is removed, but the application is no longer resizable. I need to hide the title bar completely and still allow the window to be resizable.

This issue can be reproduced on native windows. It relates to the winui3 issue, When hiding titlebar a few white pixels still show on top #8947
